# SSIS - Stored Procedure Has An Input Parameter That Runs Different Queries In The Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I am trying to use only one stored procedure for multiple packages in SSIS. An input parameter executes different sections of the procedure. It seems that SSIS gets "confused" and only sees the first result set. Is there any way to accomplish this or do I need to split the stored procedure up into multiple procedures?

Example:

```
If @Section = 1
BEGIN
   Run this section of the stored proc.
END

If @Section = 2
BEGIN
   Run this section of the stored proc.
END

If @Section = 3
BEGIN
   Run this section of the stored proc.
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a seriously bad design idea - **don't do it!** The little bit you gain by having just one procedure is tiny, compared to the hassle of maintenance, the horrible execution plans you'll get and many more issue with this approach. Might *look* smart at first - it's not - dump it. Embrace the **Single Responsibility Principle** - each piece of code should do **one thing and ONE thing only** - and do it well

Answer (score 0):

As Marc_S said, DON'T DO IT.

If you sections return different schemas, I mean, different results with different fields, SSIS will not be able to map it. SSIS is xml based and is not "that" dynamic.

Maybe this can help you: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/